# Get result from awk using two delimiters in a single command

Tags: shell-script, awk

Output of just the ping command:

```
[root@servera ~]# ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=8.04 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=7.47 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=7.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=7.50 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.473/7.683/8.037/0.225 ms
```

I want to just capture the integer 4 from the "4 received".

`ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | awk -F ',' '/received/ { print $2 }'`

The result is  `4 received`. I want to capture just the number 4 from the above command. How can I do that? The delimiter is space now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk '/received/{print $4}'
```

e.g. using `cat file` to get the same input for `awk` as in your question:

```
$ cat file
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=8.04 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=7.47 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=7.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=7.50 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.473/7.683/8.037/0.225 ms
```

```
$ cat file | awk '/received/{print $4}'
4
```

Obviously just replace `cat file` with `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` for your real testing.

In response to the OPs comment below asking what line it's matching on:

```
$ awk '/received/' file
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms
```

and why field number 4 is the one to print:

```
$ awk '/received/{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, "<" $i ">"}' file
1 <4>
2 <packets>
3 <transmitted,>
4 <4>
5 <received,>
6 <0%>
7 <packet>
8 <loss,>
9 <time>
10 <3007ms>
```

Comment: Can you explain how the integer 4 aligns to fourth field? When you do `{print $4}`, which line and which filed number is it printing ? Just want to understand the process.

Comment: On the line: `4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms`
field 1. `4`
field 2.`packets`
field 3. `transmitted,`
field 4. `4`

The awk is selecting the line that matches `received`

Comment: @Cruise5 I added a breakdown of what the script is doing at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You have already gotten some fine awk answers, so here are a few alternatives.

1. GNU `grep`

   ```
   $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '\d+(?= received,)'
   4
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\d+) received,/'
   4
   ```
3. sed

   ```
   $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | sed -En 's/.*, ([0-9]+) received,.*/\1/p'
   4
   ```

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to do this with `awk` (similar to comment on one of the answers)

```
awk -F, '/received/ {print int($2)}'
```

function `int()` will "discard" nonnumber information after the first number

Comment: Or `$2+0` should work too, +1 anyway

Answer (score 6):

The field separator can be a regular expression, so you can set multiple field delimiters in awk using `[ ]` such as:

```
awk -F '[, ]' '/received/ {print $5}'
```

However in this case I would probably just remove the word received:

```
 awk -F, '/received/ {sub(/received/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

The awk sub() function `sub(regexp, replacement [, target])` will find the pattern represented by the regular expression, replace it with *replacement*, and can optionally be narrowed to a *target* column.

Comment: I wonder if it would anger the awk gods if you simply forced numeric conversion of the field i.e. `awk -F, '/received/ {print $2+0}'` ?

Comment: What is the function of `sub and "" in the parenthesis)`?

Comment: `/received/ {sub(/received/, "", $2); print $2}` = `sub(/received/, ""){print $2}` in this case, but it still leaves undesirable blanks either way.

Comment: +1 for answering the question as asked, rather than providing workarounds. You never know when someone will *actually* need 2 separate delimiters an stumble on this thread.

Comment: @shadowtalker Conversely, sometimes they're asking the wrong question, i.e. it's an XY problem.

Comment: @Barmar indeed, my point is that it's good to consider both.

Answer (score 3):

```
 ping -c4 <ipadress>|awk '/received/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /received/){print $(i-1)}}}'
```

output

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the answers here are good at addressing OP's specific rqeuirements.

However, none of them address the general question of splitting a field on a delimiter other than the "main" delimiter used by the main AWK loop.

**The answer is to use the `split()` function**, available in all AWK versions that I know of, including the [One True AWK](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/master/awk.1) and the [POSIX specification](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/awk.1p.html):

```c
/received/ {
  split($2, recv, " "); print(recv[1])
}
```

This emits `4` on stdout:

```bsh
awk -F ',' '
/received/ {
  split($2, recv, " "); print(recv[1])
}
' <<\EOD
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=8.04 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=7.47 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=7.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=7.50 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.473/7.683/8.037/0.225 ms
EOD
```

Note `split()` has the same semantics as top-level record splitting with `FS`. That is, it should behave exactly like a second delimiter. This is implied by (but not explicitly stated in) the POSIX specification, and is explicitly stated in the GNU AWK manual page. The main effect of this that (like `FS`) if the separator pattern is `" "`, leading and trailing whitespace is stripped and consecutive whitespace characters are treated as single spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Bash command line:

```
recv=( $(ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | grep received) ); echo ${recv[3]}
```

Capture the result of 'ping' piped to 'grep' as the array 'recv'; display the 3rd element of the array.

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do it in the most awk fashion without physically counting fields :

```
mawk NF RS='^.+tted,[ \t]*|[ \t]*recei.+$' testfile4.txt

4
```

If you use the quick printout feature from gawk, you can see that RT matches the entire tail of it :

```
RT: " received, 0% packet loss, time 3007ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.473/7.683/8.037/0.225 ms\n"
```